# prefersStatusBarHidden isn't getting called

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a standard Master-Detail Application, and I'm trying to conditionally show/hide the status bar.

Overriding `prefersStatusBarHidden()` in MasterViewController does nothing. It never even gets called.

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Setting `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` in Info.plist doesn't help, presumably since `YES` is already the default value. Calling `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` doesn't help either.

I am targeting iOS 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a little bit cleaner solution. There is a function `childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden` which is specifically designed to return a child view controller to which prefersStatusBarHidden should be forwarded.

So, it will be better to override it. It will look like this:

```
override func childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden() -> UIViewController? {
    if var topViewController = self.viewControllers.first {
        if let navigationController = topViewController as? UINavigationController {
            topViewController = navigationController.topViewController!
        }
        return topViewController
    }

    return super.childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden()
}
```

And probably you can even omit following. NavigationViewController has childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden() on it's own which will send it to child viewcontroller.

```
  if let navigationController = topViewController as? UINavigationController {
      topViewController = navigationController.topViewController!
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to override `prefersStatusBarHidden()` starting from the window's root view controller. In a Master-Detail Application, this requires subclassing `UISplitViewController` to forward the message down the view controller hierarchy.

Something like this:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    if var topViewController = self.viewControllers.first {
        if let navigationController = topViewController as? UINavigationController {
            topViewController = navigationController.topViewController!
        }
        return topViewController.prefersStatusBarHidden()
    }

    return super.prefersStatusBarHidden()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine doing it for all your split view controllers, this works for me:

```
extension UISplitViewController {
    override open var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return (viewControllers.last as? UINavigationController)?.visibleViewController
}
```

}