# Hide statusbar on one viewcontroller for iOS 9

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios9, statusbar

I have `ViewController1` which uses segue to show `ViewController2`. Both of them are part of UINavigationController.

I have a button on `ViewController2` which should hide the statusbar.

I went through several Stackoverflow questions regarding this and found following, but still can't get it working:

- In Info.plist set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to `true`
- In ViewController2 I added a method     `override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool` and I return `true` or `false` (based on whether button was clicked or not)
- I call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` when a button clicked to force statusbar change be picked up.
- I read about `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance` (that it needs to be enabled). I tried to set it to `true` `prepareForSegue` on ViewController2

However, the status bar is still shown and prefersStatusBarHidden was never called.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your view controller is in a UINavigationController interface. Thus it is the navigation controller that is consulted by the runtime about the status bar, not your view controller.

However, the navigation controller in its turn will consult your view controller, so it should be sufficient to say `self.navigationController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` to set the ball rolling. It works fine for me:

[image]

Comment: got it. What should a solution should look like? Should I subclass UINavigationController? I saw that Photo app allows to zoom into a picture and this will hide a status bar (and this Photo app looks like using navigation controller too).

Comment: It should be sufficient to say `self.navigationController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`. Am I right that this was a push segue and we're in a navigation controller? Because if I'm wrong and we did a modal segue (so that this is a presented view controller), it's a different situation.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It's navigation controller and it was a push segue.

Comment: Try just the code I've given, keep the rest of what you've got, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I tried it. It still doesn't call prefersStatusBarHidden (and status bar isn't hidden).

Comment: Then I'm afraid you will have to subclass UINavigationController. I didn't want to make you do that, because you should have to, but that would certainly put you in the driver's seat.

Comment: I don't understand why it isn't working for you. It works fine for me. I'll post a screencast in a moment.

Comment: Added a screencast. This should just work. Unless of course you meant the navigation bar and the whole "status bar" question is a red herring?

Comment: I truly meant status bar. Let me try it in a small standalone project (it looks like there is something else which influence the behavior).

Comment: Matt, do you mind sending me a project which you used for screencas? I just created new Master-Detail application, applied to it all my steps + yours and it still doesn't work. My email is victor dot ronin at gmail dot com . I really appreciate it.

Comment: No, I think _you_ are the one who needs to be explicit about what _you_ are doing. I've proved that this works as advertised. You didn't even reveal in your question that this was in an UINavigationController! I had to guess even that. And you've given no other information about what's actually going. It's not my job to write your code, it's your job to ask your question fully and candidly.

Comment: Matt, I wasn't aware that  UINavigationController is in charge in this situation. As result I didn't know that it makes sense to mention it (I appreciate that you helped me to figure it out). I was explicit what I was doing (trying to hide a status bar). I was explicit about what isn't working (that prefersStatusBarHidden wasn't called).  I believe my question showed that I did prior research. As soon as you wrote the answer I tried it out myself. You are right, it's not your job to write a code for me. However, I don't think that I did anything wrong here.

Comment: "As soon as you wrote the answer I tried it out myself" Well, as my screencast shows, if you try it out yourself on a plain vanilla project consisting of just two view controllers and a navigation controller and the status-bar code, it does work. Now you need to compare that to what _you_ are doing. But I can't make that comparison for you because _you still have not revealed what you are really doing!_ Only you know, so only you can see the difference between the working example and the non-working example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to matt's answer and [Chris Hulbert's article about StatusBar](http://www.splinter.com.au/2015/12/30/status-bar-colours/) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670767/prefersstatusbarhidden-isnt-getting-called).

Apparently, you need to make sure that everybody in your ViewController hierarchy forward `prefersStatusBarHidden` to appropriate child.

There are some iOS controllers which do that (as example UINavigationViewController) and there are some which don't (they don't know to which one they should forward it). If you have any of them (as example UISplitViewController) then you need to subclass it and override childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden and write a code to forward it to appropriate child.